# Android checkbox Listview recycling is causing unexpected box checking

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I am developing an app using a ListView with a simple custom adapter, each row containing a CheckBox object.  However, due to ListView's recycling feature (that I don't plan on turning off), when any of the boxes are checked, others below or above in the ListView are also checked.

The following is my **getView()** in the adapter, along with the custom ViewHolder class:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.populate_friends_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.nameCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.isFriend);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.nameCheckBox.setText(data.get(position).contactLabel);
    holder.nameCheckBox.setChecked(checked.get(position));
    holder.nameCheckBox.setTag(String.valueOf(position));   // to properly track the actual position
    holder.nameCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            int pos = Integer.parseInt(buttonView.getTag().toString());
            checked.set(pos, isChecked);
        }

    });

    return convertView;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public CheckBox nameCheckBox;
}
```

I am already holding the checked boxes in the ArrayList of booleans: checked.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using `String` for the checkbox's tag instead of `Integer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're calling `holder.nameCheckBox.setChecked(checked.get(position));` to configure the view to be displayed for this view, the listener is called while the tag still has the position of the previous checkbox.

Try removing the listener (setting it to `null`) before calling `setChecked`